# Bootstrap 5 break button-group in specific place depending on resolution

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

How can I force line-break in specific place of button-group below specific screen size ?
I have button-group with 4 buttons in line. I want to break it into two lines AFTER first button if there is not enough space.

```html
<div class="input-group" role="group">
  <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">Add</a>
  </div>
     
  <!-- Line break when screen width<=600 -->
    
  <input type="text" class="form-control">

  <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupClear">
    <a href="#"><img src="backspace.svg" height="16px;" onclick="clearSearch()"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupSearch">
    <a href="#"><img src="search.svg" height="16px;" onClick="submit()"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your question should include the code you're working with.  What have you tried to achieve this responsive change to Bootstrap's button group component?

Comment: I have tried to add <br> with @media (max-width: 600px) display:none but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you clarify what the output code should be? In your example you're using `input-group` but your title and comments suggest you are trying to build a `btn-group`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the title, but the problem is same for the btn-group and input-group. If I shrink screen, I want to break line after "Add" button. Currently, when shrinking width, last buttons goes to the next line. The code is just example. I want to know, how can I control line breaks when screen width is too narrow to display complete btn-group or input-group.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you're 'fighting' against Bootstrap's flex-box display for `input` and `btn` groups. Can you update your code to show us what the final output is now?  The "I have a button group with 4 buttons in line" bit from your original post.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `.button-group` and `.input-group` are different concepts in Bootstrap. Your question is about `.button-group` but you're not using any, from what I can see. Please be very specific and state in clear (so that it cannot be misinterpreted) what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this SCSS:

```scss
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .wrapping-group:not(#_) > * {
    &:first-child {
      flex: 1 0 100%;
      border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      .btn {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    &:not(:first-child) {
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
    &.form-control {
      margin-left: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

working demo:

```css
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:first-child {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:first-child .btn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: -1px;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*.form-control {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
}


/* not part of solution: */

body {
  padding: 5rem 1rem 1rem
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group wrapping-group" role="group">
  <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupAddon">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">Add</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Line break when screen width<=600 -->

  <input type="text" class="form-control">

  <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupClear">
    <a href="#"><img src="backspace.svg" height="16px;" onclick="clearSearch()"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group-text" id="btnGroupSearch">
    <a href="#"><img src="search.svg" height="16px;" onClick="submit()"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You'll have to apply `wrapping-group` class to the group you want this behavior on, so it doesn't apply to all `.input-group`s.
Also, I used Bootstrap 5's xs/sm breakpoint (`576px`) instead of `600px` but you can change it to whatever makes sense for your case.

Comment: Great! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

[@tao answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67494324/12716228) is really help me, i modify the css little bit, maybe someone need it, but sorry i cant explain, im new in css

```css
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:first-child {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:first-child .btn {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:not(:first-child) {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*.form-control {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .wrapping-group:not(#_)>*:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group wrapping-group" role="group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">

  <div class="input-group-text d-grid gap-2" id="btnGroupClear">
    <a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
</svg>
</a>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group-text d-grid gap-2" id="btnGroupSearch">
    <a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M2.146 2.854a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L8 7.293l5.146-5.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l5.147 5.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-5.146 5.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 2.146 2.854Z"/>
</svg></a>
  </div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have used css at display:block;